# Loop that will iterate a certain number of times through a CSV in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

I have a large CSV file (~250000 rows) and before I work on fully parsing and sorting it I was trying to display only a part of it by writing it to a text file.

```
   csvfile = open(file_path, "rb")
   rows = csvfile.readlines()
   text_file = open("output.txt", "w")
   row_num = 0
   while row_num < 20:
       text_file.write(", ".join(row[row_num]))
       row_num += 1
   text_file.close()
```

I want to iterate through the CSV file and write only a small section of it to a text file so I can look at how it does this and see if it would be of any use to me. Currently the text file ends up empty.

A way I thought might do this would be to iterate through the file with a for loop that exits after a certain number of iteration but I could be wrong and I'm not sure how to do this, any ideas?

Comment: You seem to be missing a `for row in rows:` line.

Comment: @joelgoldstick where?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing specifically wrong with what you're doing, but it's not particularly Pythonic. In particular reading the whole file into memory with `readlines()` at the start seems pointless if you're only using 20 lines.

Instead you could use a for loop with enumerate and break when necessary.

```
csvfile = open(file_path, "rb")
text_file = open("output.txt", "w")
for i, row in enumerate(csvfile):
    text_file.write(row)
    if row_num >= 20:
        break
text_file.close()
```

You could further improve this by using `with` blocks to open the files, rather than closing them explicitly. For example:

```
with open(file_path, "rb") as csvfile:
    #your code here involving csvfile
#now the csvfile is closed!
```

Also note that Python might not be the best tool for this - you could do it directly from Bash, for example, with just `head -n20 csvfile.csv > output.txt`.

Comment: Thanks! I need to read the whole file in as at the moment I'm working with a small part of the file to test how is best to parse it as the file's order is a bit unpredictable but in the long run I'll need the whole file. This doesn't seem to work, the output text file is still empty. I'll try the with blocks. Also I have to use python for this project.

Comment: @Clíodhna the code should work (except you didn't close `csvfile`). Are you looking at the right directory?

Comment: Sorry, a bit of a copy-and-paste error, I've updated the line that does the writing.

Comment: No, sorry, file still ends up empty. It shows that it was edited but nothing is in the file. From adding a few test print statements it would appear that the program never enters the loop `for i, row in enumerate(csvfile):` If I change it to `for i, row in enumerate(rows):` it works perfectly, thanks! :)

Comment: @MoonCheesez whoops forgot to copy that bit, I have a line underneath that snippet of code that closes the csv file

Comment: @DanielRoseman, it should be `with open(file_path, "rb") as csvfile:` instead `with csvfile as open(file_path, "rb"):`. No?

Comment: @HEADLESS_0NE That bit was edited in by someone else; corrected.

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution would be to just do :

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- encoding: utf-8 -*-

file_path = './test.csv'
with open(file_path, 'rb') as csvfile:
    with open('output.txt', 'wb') as textfile:
        for i, row in enumerate(csvfile):
            textfile.write(row)
            if i >= 20:
                break
```

---

*Explanation :*

```
with open(file_path, 'rb') as csvfile:
with open('output.txt', 'wb') as textfile:
```

Instead of using `open` and `close`, it is recommended to use this line instead. Just write the lines that you want to execute when your file is opened into a new level of indentation.

`'rb'` and `'wb'` are the keywords you need to open a file in respectively `'reading'` and `'writing'` in `'binary mode'`

```
for i, row in enumerate(csvfile):
```

This line allows you to read line by line your CSV file, and using a tuple `(i, row)` gives you both the content of the row and its index. That's one of the awesome built-in functions from Python : check out [here](https://speakerdeck.com/pyconslides/transforming-code-into-beautiful-idiomatic-python-by-raymond-hettinger-1) for more about it.

Hope this helps !

---

**EDIT :** Note that Python has a [CSV package](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) that can do that without `enumerate` :

```
# -*- encoding: utf-8 -*-

import csv

file_path = './test.csv'
with open(file_path, 'rb') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    with open('output.txt', 'wb') as textfile:
        writer = csv.writer(textfile)
        i = 0
        while i<20:
            row = next(reader)
            writer.writerow(row)
            i += 1
```

All we need to use is its `reader` and `writer`. They have functions `next` (that reads one line) and `writerow` (that writes one). Note that here, the variable `row` is not a string, but a list of strings, because the function does the `split` job by itself. It might be faster than the previous solution.

Also, this has the major advantage of allowing you to *look* anywhere you want in the file, no necessarily from the beginning (just change the bounds for `i`)

Comment: I don't think the `#!/usr/bin/python` is necessary (they may be using virtualenv or another OS).

Comment: Your comment makes perfect sense, I think OP can omit this line without any damage.